# Bash tab completion for command called by time

Tags: bash, tab-completion

A custom command based (`complete -C ...`) completion works fine when invoked from the top level. Like

```
my-command <Tab>
```

Completion code

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

The completion command is provided with 3 arguments - completed command name, current word and previous word - and 4 envirnoment variables - `COMP_KEY`, `COMP_LINE`, `COMP_POINT`, `COMP_TYPE` - as described in documentation chapter [Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).

However when invoked with `time` prefix (to measure execution time), like

```
time my-command <Tab>
```

the completion command is invoked without `COMP_LINE` and `COMP_POINT` environment variables set and arguments are set to `compget`, current word and empty string. Also warning

```
bash: compgen: warning: -C option may not work as you expect
```

is printed.

I have 2 questions

- Is the changed way the completion command is called result of insufficient implementation of completion for `time` command, or general limitation of command based completion (`complete -C`)?
- How to make it work? How to get rid of the warning and get necessary state data from the completion command - at least a string of line being completed and current cursor position?

Comment: `A custom command based (complete -C ...) completion works fine` please present a _full_ mcve? Please post the full "custom command based completion" part. `time ls -<tab>` works fine for me.

Comment: @KamilCuk Example with `ls` works fine likely since it doesn't use `complete -C` type completion but rather `complete -F`. On my system `$ complete -p ls` ouputs `complete -F _longopt ls`.

Comment: `Completion code` is this some rust code? Is it bash? Can you post what have I to type in the terminal, so that I get the same warning? `complete -C <what here?> my-command` and then `time my-command <tab>`. `the completion command is invoked without` Can you post how are you checking that the completion command has no these variables? I am looking for an mcve.

Comment: So I created a script `1.sh` with the content `#!/bin/bash` `env > /tmp/1` `echo foo`, then typed `complate -C ./1.sh mycommand` and then typed `time mycommand <tab>`. Indeed _then_ I get the same warning. Still I see `COMP*` variables in `/tmp/1`, so it is invoked with these environment variables and I can't reproduce that.

Comment: After inspecting `complete -p time` and `declare -f _command _command_offset` and the output of `set -x` from the shell, it seems it calls `compgen -C ./1.sh --` which just [shows this warning](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3a35a2d601a55f337f8ca02a541f8c033682247/builtins/complete.def#L690).